# Non-persistent Windows VDI with user profiles

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, roaming-profile, vdi

We operate a Windows virtual desktop infrastructure with around 30 virtual machines. We have around 300 different users. All of them access the machines in arbitrary order and frequency. Each user has a own profile and settings that need to be loaded on logon. Every machine is reverted to a clean state before any user gets the chance to login. Currently we use Roaming Profiles. Unfortunately the performance of our VDI got worse when we switched from Windows 7 over to Windows 10 and decreased even more even though we haven't changed anything except the Windows 10 major version. More precisely, the logon takes roughly 1 minute 30 seconds when loading an average profile. This is way too slow.

Unfortunately, we can't alter the hardware on which the profiles are stored, so no upgrade possibility here. 
The question is how can we improve the logon times without storing all user profiles and fetching them regularly? We can't store the user profiles directly on the machine because currently we have to revert the whole machine to ensure that there are no side-effects, e.g. malware or misconfiguration from a user. 
We use VMware ESXi 6.7.0 and Win10 1909. We already tried to optimize our golden image by using VMwares OS Optimization Tool and their Win10 1909 preset. This improved the logon time to the current logon time of ~1:30min.

Comment: Are you using Folder Redirection?

Comment: Also - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/troubleshoot-user-profiles-events